# Future for loop does not work in Flutter and print an error

Tags: firebase, flutter, error-handling

I have a `future` function connected with a future builder to get images from `Firebase storage`. Because I'll get multiple images I created a for loop like following:

```
  FutureBuilder(
         future: getImages(),
         builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
             return ListView.builder(
               shrinkWrap: true,
               itemCount: 2,//snapshot.data.length,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                 return ListTile(
                   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                   leading: Image.network("https://placehold.it/500x500", fit: BoxFit.fill),
                 );
               });
           } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
              return Text("No data");
            }
           return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),

  getImages() async{
    var showcaseCode = await page.where("userID",isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get();
    List downloadUrlList = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < showcaseCode.docs.length; i++){
      var url = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref()
          .child("showcase_images")
          .child(showcaseCode.docs[0]["showcase_code"])
          .getDownloadURL()
          .toString();
      downloadUrlList.add(url),
    }
    return downloadUrlList;
  }
```

But it didn't work so I tried following:

```
  getImages() async{
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     print("Test");
    }
    return true;
  }
```

And I got following errors and prints in the console:

```
I/flutter ( 6870): Test 

I/chatty  ( 6870): uid=10153(com.nanowiresoft.memeon_main) 1.ui identical 8 lines

I/flutter ( 6870): Test 

W/DynamiteModule( 6870): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found. 

I/DynamiteModule(6870): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0 

W/ProviderInstaller( 6870): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0. 

I/FirebaseAuth( 6870): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation

W/System  ( 6870): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. 

D/FirebaseAuth( 6870): Notifying id token listeners about user ( gLOnpLqdStXqGbz0iHQpbBlVbN62 ).
```

I've seen this errors in other threads but I couldn't fix it. I'm new in Flutter so i don't now much. Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't see any errors here. An error will have an `E/` before the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Future` as return type. Must be working

```
 Future<List<String>> getImages() async{
    var showcaseCode = await page.where("userID",isEqualTo: 
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get();
    List downloadUrlList = [];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < showcaseCode.docs.length; i++){
        var url = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref()
        .child("showcase_images")
        .child(showcaseCode.docs[0]["showcase_code"])
        .getDownloadURL()
        .toString();

        downloadUrlList.add(url),
    } 

    return downloadUrlList;
}
```